# Filtrar inserccion en bd segun la fecha

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una aplicación en laravel, la cual gestiona las vacaciones, tengo un problema a la hora de filtrar las fechas seleccionadas por los trabajadores, ya que solo soy capaz de filtrar la fecha de inicio y final, el problema es que segun el departamento 2 trabajadores no pueden coger vacaciones en la misma fecha, pero si selecciono por ejemplo del 1 al 15 con el trabajador 1 deberia ser imposible que el trabajador 2 seleccione por ejemplo del 2 al 14, sin embargo como solo soy capaz de filtrar la fecha de inicio y final me lo acepta, y guarda con lo cual el filtro no funciona.

Mi pregunta es si no hay una manera de filtrar un intervalo de fechas, en vez de fecha inicio y fin. 
Os dejo el codigo:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'type' => 'required',
            'observations' => 'required',
            'datefilter' => 'required',
        ]);
    $dep =\DB::table('workers')->select('workers.area_id')
        ->where(['workers.id' => $request->worker_id])
        ->get();

    $vacation = new Vacation();
    $vacation -> worker_id = $request['worker_id'];
    $vacation -> type = $request['type'];
    $vacation -> observations = $request['observations'];
    $vacation -> area_id = $dep[0]->area_id;
    //parse dates
    $date  = explode('-',$request['datefilter']);
    $dateFrom = date("y-m-d",strtotime( $date[0]));
    $dateTo = date("y-m-d",strtotime($date[1]));

    $vacation -> date_from = date("y-m-d", strtotime($dateFrom));
    $vacation -> date_to = date("y-m-d", strtotime( $dateTo ));

    $guardadas_datefrom = \DB::table('vacations')
        ->where('date_from',  $dateFrom)
        ->where('area_id',  $dep[0]->area_id )
        ->get();
    $guardadas_dateto = \DB::table('vacations')
        ->where('date_to',  $dateTo)
        ->where('area_id',  $dep[0]->area_id )
        ->get();

    if(!$guardadas_datefrom && !$guardadas_dateto){
       $vacation->save();

        $data = request()->all();

       return back()->with('success','Vacaciones Solicitadas correctamente');

    }else{
        return back()->with('error','Fechas no disponibles');
    }

    return back();
}
```

Gracias de antemano. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para discernir que no haya ningún registro en el rango/periodo de tiempo indicado debes hacer 4 where anidados en la consulta. Ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM vacaciones v
WHERE 
    ( fecha_inicio >= $inicio AND fecha_fin  <= $fin )
    OR
    ( fecha_inicio >= $inicio AND fecha_fin  > $fin )
    OR
    ( fecha_inicio  < $inicio AND fecha_fin <= $fin)
    OR
    ( fecha_inicio  < $inicio AND fecha_fin > $fin)
```

1. Fecha inicio mayor o igual a inicio y fecha fin menor o igual
2. Fecha inicio mayor o igual a inicio y fecha fin mayor a fin
3. Fecha inicio menor a inicio y fecha fin menor o igual a fin
4. Fecha inicio es menor a inicio y fecha fin es mayor a fin

Visto esto pasemoslo a Eloquent

```
$guardadas = \DB::table('vacations')
    // ambas dentro del rango/periodo
    ->where(function($q) use ($inicio, $fin) {
        $q->where('date_from', '>=', $inicio)
            ->where('date_to', '<=', $fin);
    })
    // fin desborda rango/periodo pero inicio dentro rango/periodo
    ->orWhere(function($q) use ($inicio, $fin) {
        $q->where('date_from', '>=', $inicio)
            ->where('date_to', '>', $fin);
    })
    // inicio desborda rango/periodo pero fin dentro de rango/periodo
    ->orWhere(function($q) use ($inicio, $fin) {
        $q->where('date_from', '<', $inicio)
            ->where('date_to', '<=', $fin);
    })
    // inicio y fin desbordan el rango/periodo
    ->orWhere(function($q) use ($inicio, $fin) {
        $q->where('date_from', '<', $inicio)
            ->where('date_to', '>', $fin);
    })
    // otras condiciones
    ->get();
```

Obviamente los campos de la base de datos deben ser de tipo DATE o DATETIME, así como las variables del ejemplo `$inicio` y `$fin` deven ser seteadas antes de la consulta con el formato admitido, 'YYYY-MM-DD' o 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'

---

Edit

La opcion mas completa utilizando Between seria la siguiente:

```
$guardadas = \DB::table('vacations')
    // ambas dentro del rango/periodo
    ->where(function($q) use ($inicio, $fin) {
        $q->where('date_from', '>=', $inicio)
            ->where('date_to', '<=', $fin);
    })
    // fin desborda rango/periodo pero inicio dentro rango/periodo
    ->orWhere(function($q) use ($inicio, $fin) {
        $q->whereBetween('date_from', [$inicio, $fin])
            ->where('date_to', '>', $fin);
    })
    // inicio desborda rango/periodo pero fin dentro de rango/periodo
    ->orWhere(function($q) use ($inicio, $fin) {
        $q->where('date_from', '<', $inicio)
            ->whereBetween('date_to', [$inicio, $fin]));
    })
    // inicio y fin desbordan el rango/periodo
    ->orWhere(function($q) use ($inicio, $fin) {
        $q->where('date_from', '<', $inicio)
            ->where('date_to', '>', $fin);
    })
    // otras condiciones
    ->get();
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Xerif, tu nombre te honra jeje, funciono perfectamente. Saludos.

Comment: No hay de que. Aún que hay un caso que ko quedo cubierto por mi respuesta y es si ambas fechas inicio y fin desbordan el rango. Faltaría añadir un `orWhere` más en el que: `date_from<$inicio AND date_to>$fin` esto se me paso por alto pero habría que tenerlo en cuentas pues si por ejemplo: un registro empieza del día 1 al 31 y tu buscas del 10 al 20 quedaría como libre aún que esta dentro del periodo. Espero haberme explicado. Luego te edito para añadir esto también  a la respuesta.

Comment: Vale, si lo he testeado, y efectivamente tienes razón, intentare arreglarlo, aunque se agradece el aporte. Saludos.

Comment: @DavidPazóLópez ya te edite la respuesta, tal como está ahora deberian quedar todos los casos cubiertos. Un saludo

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, va perfecto ahora. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que en tu caso no habría problema en usar whereBetween y orWhereBetween.
Si existen resultados el empleado no podrá tomar vacaciones T__T

```
$conflictivas = \DB::table('vacations')
                   ->whereBetween('date_from', [$inicio, $fin])
                   ->orWhereBetween('date_to', [$inicio, $fin])
                   ->get();
```

Comment: lo probare, solo por tener conocimiento de otra manera de hacerlo, muchas gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: Es una manera muy "larvel" ya que es simple de entender sin mucho esfuerzo, por cualquiera que vea el código, que justamente es una de las virtudes de laravel, que en otras cosas se cae un poco.  Espero que te sirva, aunque no deberías tener problemas.  Saludos.